# Scroll bug on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am working on this site right now: https://handyfreak011.github.io/FreetimeElements/. 
I tested the website on mobile devices and found the problem i couldn't solve.
If you for example test the site on 768px devices you are able to scroll to the right and see the red background...
How do I disable this scrolling to the right ? 
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use appropriate classes,

If you want to give `offset-xs-*` then subtract it from grid system of `12` then set cols `col-xs-*`

In you case,

For xs device

```
<div class="col-xs-11 offset-xs-1">
```

For medium devices

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2">
```

Final

```
<div class="col-xs-11 offset-xs-1 col-md-10 offset-md-2 p-y-3">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The solution i use with bootstrap's grid system isn't the best..I should try something else!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you have a `"offset-xs-1 offset-md-2"` class inside your `#social` div. These classes are causing the "overflow" issue wich you're having. Try using different classes to achieve that layout or if it's impossible use `overflow: hidden;` on your `#social` div